# How to display a map by mapkit framework in iphone using URL like http://maps.google.com....[it opens map as new App]

Tags: iphone, mapkit

When we open : http://maps.google.com & type :  category:"motel"+California+USA we get the California region map with the motels in that region. This is done by using MapsApp in iphone. But it closes the current application & opens the map as New App.

Now is it possible to do the same thing with mapkit framework? How to use URL in Mapkit like

http://maps.google.com?q=category....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an [MKMapView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) to your application. Take a look at "Specifying the Visible Map Region" to center it on California.

As for showing motels, you would have to handle that manually. You could use a service to find the hotels and then add them to your MKMapView as MKAnnotations.

Comment: Thanks bpapa, for your positive response.
Please Can I get more details about which services provide  such information regarding motels & How to implement the same.

I went through google API. But I did not find the way to get information like coordinates, Name, address, contact details, etc. about motels.

So if anybody has done such thing before then please give some guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could look into the API for foursquare, although their database is very new and might not have everything that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks bpapa. I went through this API for foursquare, but its not that much helpful yet